# Define ellipse and hyperbola in terms of distances from a point

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Just as we say a circle is a locus of points that are equidistant from a single point.

How to define an ellipse and a hyperbola in a similar way?

Comment: Have you tried to check the internet?

Comment: See the definition of conic sections, btw this is not a physics question

Comment: Checking the internet is cheating, I suggest Scooby takes a piece of paper and pencil and starts to do some serious work on this problem.

Comment: Learning from internet is ok, but some help is needed sometimes.

Comment: The usual definition of a conic is in terms of the focus, directrix and the eccentricity http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicSectionDirectrix.html

Answer (score 1):

Let $d(X, Y)$ be the distance between the points $X$ and $Y$ in the plane. Consider two points $P, Q$ in the plane (the [foci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Focus_%28geometry%29)), and let $c>0$.

The ellipse is the locus of those $M$ such that $d(M,P) + d(M,Q) = c$.

The hyperbola is the locus of those points $M$ such that $|d(M,P) - d(M,Q)| = c$.

Answer (score 1):

Ellipses and hyperbolas cannot be defined with respect to a *single* center as you expect. It takes either two centers or a center and axis to define them. In the former case it has to be their sum or difference, and in the latter ratio of distances to the defining point.

Hope you find relation between *two* segment lengths, as others defined.